# How to create a second frontpage in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

How to create a second (or more) front page in Joomla? (Joomla 3.1.5 here)?!

My dream website would be a website with several Homepages, but I haven't figured yet how to make it....
What I mean: for example if you have website on sports - you want a Homepage for: Hockey, Football and Basketball
- each with all 18 (or so) template positions, full page of Modules, etc....Exactly like it is on actual Front Page, but each on different topic....

How to do this?!

---

and how to get over 'question quality standarts' - everything is described above;

Comment: Are each of these homepages on different subdomains?

Comment: What do you mean several 'homepages'? A homepage is just the page that shows when you go to the base domain (typically). What would a visitor have to do to tell the system which page it wants? Typically you have one homepage and a url that distinguishes each other page. Does that not work for you?

Comment: If you want help I'd suggest being more specific about what your trying to achieve.

Comment: Basically you can pretend each sport is a different language (so you'll have to make fake language packs) and follow the instructions for multilingual, but it's an inherently complex task and you must read the docs carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create menu items, assign them to different templates, assign the modules et voilà.

Create the new featured menu items and filter them by category, assuming one is Hockey, Golf etc.

[image: Featured menu item]

Then in the template manager, install your new template or create a new style for one of the templates based on your requirements, and assign the newly created menu item.

[image: Template manager-assign menu items]

If you're looking for a howto, you might want to start from Joomla.org or google.

It's not a matter of quality, but of context. This is a developers site, not a Joomla usage forum.

Comment: I'm using Joomla for long time; there is no such feature as I'm asking in default; I've been digging internet, I can't find anything on this topic.

Comment: I added the screenshots, hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: No, I see you just don't understand a problem and trying to show me some basic things.

Comment: I answered your question: how to get multiple homepages. Do you have other requirements you haven't shared or I misinterpreted? Are you implying multi-domain access to the homepages i.e. basked.yoursite.com and golf.yoursite.com?

Comment: To improve on my previous comments: several plugins allow you to map a menu item to a subdomain or different domain, look here http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites

Answer (score 1):

'Riccardo Zorn' did answer this question pretty well.

What you basically wan't to do is to create a website with kind of a following structure.

site:

- 1: category 1 (sport x)
- 2: category 2 (sport y)
- - 2.1: subcategory to 2(sport y ~ men)
- - 2.2: subcategory to 2(sport y ~ women)
    ...

While each category would be a seperate menu as well as very likely a different template.
It is up to you to filter for the templates and menues which modules are shown there.
But you will have one basic entry point for the website.

No offense but what you want to do is basically default in joomla since at least version 1.6

Comment: No, what you both say are just some well known basic things; I didn't came here to ask that; I need another front page or blank page retaining all my front page type positions and layout; There are page types for each type of page like: Article pages/k2 item pages and categories; but I need a Front page. It is a well known problem where people are usually trying to: Use a blank article or use Blank component, none of which I like well....

Comment: The frontpage of joomla isn't any special kind of menu item except for the parameter that it is defined as the starting point.

The frontpage itself is nothing more like for example a menu item configured to show articles from a category /featured categories / content from a component.

You either have left out some information in your question or you just don't get what we are suggesting.

Comment: Right @DanielBöttner , I think Red Zambala should try to clarify his requirements. Additionally, he's asked 5 questions, received a dozen answers, and accepted none.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a total different requirements that what you have described, one way to achieve what you are after for in Joomla 3, is to create several featured articles menu-items with the category settings you want, and also configure your template to work the way you want, with the module positions and the module assignments.

There are also other custom content components, you may want to try, like k2, that offers a variety of options when creating blog layout pages.

And to add to Daniel Bottner's comment that under conditions, this was also possible even with J1.5.

similar simple example in J1.5:
[example-page1](http://www.news.935radio.gr/%CF%80%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%BF%CE%BD%CE%BD%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%BF%CF%82.html)
[example-page2](http://www.news.935radio.gr/%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%BA%CF%89%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%B1.html)